# How can I get first 10-bits of UInt16 type?

Tags: c#-4.0, casting

I want to take first 10-bits value of UInt16 value. I tried;

```
x = (x & 0x00001111111111 )
```

But it gives me an `error : Cannot convert type 'int' to 'ushort'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, as 0x3FF in binary is 0000 0011 1111 1111

```
x = (UInt16)(x & 0x3FF)
```

Comment: You missed the casting initially;)

Comment: Tried your solution but gives the same error. "Cannot implicitly convert type'int' to 'ushort'. These operations are easy but c# syntax  always gives smt errors..

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
UInt16 val1 = 8; 
UInt16 value = (UInt16)(val1 << 6);
```

or simply cast it like this:-

```
x = (UInt16)(x & 0x3FF)
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, second solution is same as the below. It worked.